# Multiplication of corresponding array elements in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multiplication

Is there a Java function that can take as parameters two Arrays and multiply every element in the 1st array with the equivalent in the second array?

If there is one. How is that function more efficient in comparison to a `for loop`?

`Array 1`

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

`Array 2`

```
4, 3, 2, 1
```

Result:

```
4, 6, 6, 4
```

Comment: I don't think there any readily available libraries to perform this type of operation.

Comment: Go with the `for` loop. They're underappreciated.

Comment: I don't get the question. This would be very simple to implement yourself.

Comment: @DanW The question is if there is a library that can perform that kind of operations more efficient than a for loop.

Comment: Why are you worried so much about efficiency? Is there a wider context that would be useful to know about?

Comment: Is this multiplication a bottleneck in your application, or are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: unless you know there is a chance that you produce an infinite loop, there is no efficiency you will gain from using a function from a library over coding it yourself.

Comment: @AJ yes , in the general case , there is. libraries usually have the good and right implementations. Usually when you do it yourself you try to reinvent the worst wheel first.

Comment: @Markus Mikkolainen i was not referring to general usage. i was referring to this specific case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No built in function I know of, but very simple to achieve:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] arr2 = {4, 3, 2, 1};
int[] result = new int[4];

for(int i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++) {
    result[i] = arr[i]*arr2[i];
}
```

You could potentially make the operation multi-threaded (quite easily) if you really need better performance, but aside from that I don't see a magic, huge performance boost. It's quite a cheap operation really.

Answer (score 1):

[JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) is a third party library you can use for matrix operations if you decide not to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `EJML` Library for Matrix operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<Integer> it=ar1.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> it2=ar2.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()&&it2.hasNext())
{
    result.add(new Integer(it.next().intValue()*it2.next().intValue()));
}
```

will also work efficiently for any list.